# How to load ActivityIndicatorView on TableView inside TabBarcontroller, XCode 4.2

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, xcode4.2, storyboard, uiactivityindicatorview

Xcode - version 4.2 
Target Platform - iPhone

I have a TabBarController , containing 3 tabs. All tabs contain TableViewController wired to the TabBarController via NavigationController. All TableViewController shows data from external URL, and as well have their corresponding DetailViews.

The application works all fine.

I'm unable to add an 'UIActivityIndicatorView" while the data on the TableView is being loaded. The 'storyboard' neither allows me to add the 'UIActivityIndicatorView' control on the TableViewController or UINavigationController.

**Note**  :

1. I understand placing UIActivityIndicatorView directly on a UIViewController.
2. I dont want the UIActivityIndicatorView 'loading' for the cells in the TableView.

Thanks, 
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same with Storyboard but it seems that you should bette do it programmatically :
In your ViewController.h :

```
@property (strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

In viewDidLoad :

```
    // init with desired state
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    // set the color
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);

    // set the position
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2,
                                       self.view.bounds.size.height/4);
```

If you have to handle orientation change, think to update the position in `viewWillAppear` and `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

I think I'll loose less time to code that than time to find a better way to work with Storyboards